# Zend serialization is not storing relationship between objects

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm working on an app in PHP with Zend in which I need to store a list of people and the city of each one.

So I have `$person->city`.

When I get the person information I do `$person->setCity($aCity)` to setup the corresponding city information.
And person has all the information.

Then I do `$this->Sesion->People = serialize($people)` [`$people` is an array of person objects]

Then, when I do unserialize($this->Sesion->People), People just have the information about the people, not about the city of each person, so If I try to do `$person->getCity()` the result is `null` or empty, what is different to what I had before the serialize.

Is it possible to do that? Can I do it in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For serialize to work with object as requested.
You need to implement `__sleep` for `serialize` and `__wakeup` for `unserialize`

Please read http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php for more details.